# WinRT md5 hashage

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, md5

I try to get a md5 hash :

```
        String clearKey = "test";
        IBuffer buffEntry = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(clearKey, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);
        HashAlgorithmProvider algProvider = HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithmNames.Md5);

        IBuffer buffHashed = algProvider.HashData(buffEntry);

        byte[] bytesKey;
        CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(buffHashed, out bytesKey);
        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("bytesKey lenght : {0}", bytesKey.Length));
```

Why my result has a size of 16 bytes? How to get a classical 32 Bytes result?

thank you for your help,

Comment: Are you using this to derive a key from a password? In that case MD5 is clearly the wrong choice. You should use a KDF, such as PBKDF2 in that case.

Comment: no, This is part of a code that is intended to solve a byte mixed up file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MD5 has a 128 bit or 16 byte output. So it's wrong to expect 32 bytes. I assume with 32 bytes, you mean a hex encoded string, where each byte maps to two characters, resulting in a 32 character string.

In metro you can  [`CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.cryptographicbuffer.encodetohexstring.aspx). to convert bytes to a hex string.

In your case this becomes:

```
string md5Hex = CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToHexStringbuffHashed(buffEntry);
```

Comment: Thank you! but how do I convert a hexstring in byte[]? System.Convert only offer me that converting a base64 string. In fact I'm looking for the equivalent of my JAVA code : byte[] bytesKey = hashedHexString.getBytes("utf-8") which gives me a byte[] of size 32

Comment: You can use `ConvertStringToBinary` on the hex string. But why do this? This doubles the size of the hash, without gaining any security.

Comment: It's for solve a byte mixed up file, bytes and size of key are used as salt, I just find the equivalent of my java code: System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hexstring). Thank again

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/3928b8cb-3703-4672-8ccd-33718148d1e3 about halfway down is a post by Matthew Fraser who has the fastest byte->hex converter I've ever seen, and right below it my solution will convert it back from a range of formats.